# CDF of the kinetic energy of a particle under uniform distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

We are given that X~Uniform[2,3] and the kinetic energy is $T=\frac{1}{2X^2}$

I tried the following: $P(T\leq a) = P(\frac{1}{2X^2}\leq a) = P(-\sqrt{2a}\leq X \leq \sqrt{2a}) = \int_{-\sqrt{2a}}^{\sqrt{2a}} dx$ Which gives me:

$P(T\leq a) = 2\sqrt{2a}$

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your calculation of the distribution function of $T$ is wrong.

One obtains

$P\left(T\leq a\right)=P\left(\frac{1}{2X^2}\leq a\right)=P\left(\frac{1}{a}\leq X^{2}\right)=P\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}\leq X \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}\right)$

Now its your turn.

Comment: Ahh, such a silly mistake! Thanks a lot.